# How to get list of instance types using AWS .net SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2

I'm writing a program in C# to create instances in AWS. I need to get the list of available instance types to show to the user.  How can I get that list?

Answer (score 0):

one option is to look at the const class 
   Amazon.EC2.InstanceType